# Lines splitting despite using multiline logstash filter

Tags: elasticsearch, multiline, logstash

I used the multiline logstash filter.It fails at a few instances.

For Example I tried parsing a report with multiple blocks.I formed these blocks/paragraphs using multiline filter.

```
    Page 1 Date Title Author
    Data................................................................................
    ....................................................................................
    <delimiter>
```

When I tested this using 100 blocks, every time it doesn't append 1 or 2 blocks correctly.
It takes

```
Page 1 Date Title Author
```

as a single message and parses it and remaining part as another message.

**Note:**
Another observation is that at times, the 1st part of the block say

```
Page 21 Date Title Author
```

is parsed and then it is followed by

```
  Page 20 Date Title Author
        Data................................................................................
        ....................................................................................
        <delimiter>
```

the prev block and then finally the remaining part of the incomplete block is parsed.
Is this some kind of multi-threading issue?

**Edit:** 
My config file looks something like this:

```
input{
     file{
         path=>"/home/tudit/input.txt"
         start_position=>"beginning"
 }
}

filter{
    multiline{
        pattern => "^\f"
            negate => true
            what => "previous"
            enable_flush=>"true"
    }

    grok{
        match=>["message","Page%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:page_no:int}"]
    }

    grok{
        match=>["message","(?<date>%{MONTHDAY}%{SPACE}%{MONTH}%{SPACE}%{YEAR})"]
    }

    grok{
        match=>["message","Author:%{SPACE}%{WORD:author}"]
    }

    grok{
        match=>["message","Title:%{SPACE}%{WORD:title}"]
    }

    date{
        match => [ "date", "dd MMM YYYY" ]
    }

}

output {
  stdout{
    codec=>"rubydebug"
  }
 elasticsearch{
    embedded=> "true"
    host=> "localhost"
  }

}
```

\f is the delimiter.

Comment: What does your config look like?  And can you figure out a minimal file that exhibits the problem?

Comment: I added my config.It fails at the very first instance.Sometimes at other places as well.So there is no min input for which it always works.The nature in which it fails is consistent(explained in the question) but it occurs at different blocks at different times

Comment: I removed the enable_flush tag and it worked. But the last block isn't parsed.

Comment: Then its probably a problem with the enable_flush -- it was marked as experimental in 1.4.2.  Does your multi-line pattern always start and stop with a predictable pattern?  If so, I wrote a plugin that can handle that that I will post as an answer if it would work for you.